# android check if mobile network is ckecked in setting or not

Tags: android

I would like to know if mobile flag in setting is checked or not.

With this threads I can check if 3g is connected or not but i can not see if checkbox for enable it is enabled or not in setting

[How to check if wifi/3g is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782790/how-to-check-if-wifi-3g-is-enabled)
[Google Android - how to figure out if 3g and 2g is turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763972/google-android-how-to-figure-out-if-3g-and-2g-is-turned-on)
[Android: How to check whether 3G is enabled or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743477/android-how-to-check-whether-3g-is-enabled-or-not)

How can i check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is return true if internet connection is available else return false.

```
public boolean getConnection()
        {
            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                                    .isConnectedOrConnecting();
            boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(
                                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                                    .isConnectedOrConnecting();

                        Log.v("",is3g + " ConnectivityManager Test " + isWifi);
                        if (!is3g && !isWifi) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your internet connction is OFF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return false;


                        } else 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return true;

                        }
    }
```

If this is not satisfy above answer then you can use try-catch.  If you does not receive data that means your connection has problem.